# immutability of primitive types, Are these two values ​using the same memory address

Tags: javascript

```
let a = 10;
let b = a;
```

a -> 10
b -> 10

Are these two values ​​using the same memory address?

Comment: No. This isn't C (thankfully).

Comment: @caTS Even in C, these variables would not have the same memory address. As far as I know, all programming languages don't take references to primitives unless explicitly told to.

Comment: I think this question may not be really answerable as-is - JavaScript is too high-level to have a concept of "memory address". Now, if one was asking about a specific engine (like V8), one could look at *its* code to see what it's doing

Comment: However, this question is almost certainly a duplicate. I have a hard time believing this hasn't already been asked.

Comment: @MichaelM.: The language spec addresses observable behavior, not memory allocation. Even the section labeled "memory model" is really about operation ordering and operation visibility between threads; it doesn't have anything to do with memory allocation.

Comment: This code could produce a single representation of `10` in memory and two references to that representation, CPython style, or two separate representations of `10` in memory, or it could even optimize out both variables, or write them to disk or something.

Comment: By 'these two values' do you actually mean 'these two variables (a and b)'? Or do you mean is a representation of 10 held in two different places or in one? I am not clear what you are asking.